# It is possible to run SonarQube 6.2 on 512ram VPS

Tags: jvm, sonarqube, freebsd

I'm trying to run SonarQube 6.2 on VPS but it has only 512mb ram (recommended to use SonarQube is 1gb memory) While I start SonarQube I exceed ram limit to above 1gb ram.

My VPS spec:

```
FreeBSD 10.3-STABLE
hw.machine: amd64
hw.model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
hw.ncpu: 8
```

So, my question is: It is possible to configure SonarQube proccess limited to 512mb ram to run on this server?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Consider a [cloud solution](https://writeabout.net/2016/04/25/setup-sonarqube-in-azure-vm).

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try by using/adding more  [swap](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) to compensate the lack of memory, but from the list of requirements seems you need at least 2GB:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements